# Can threads mix written values?

Tags: c++, multithreading

As a hobby project I'm toying around with creating a programming language with garbage collection.
The language will be compiled to (preferably portable) C++ and supports threads.

The question is:
Support two threads writes "simultaneously" different values to the same (pointer-sized and aligned) memory location.
Is it then possible for any thread to read a mix between the two values?

For example on a 32 bit platform:

Thread 1 writes: AAAAAAAA

Thread 2 writes: BBBBBBBB

Will any thread always read AAAAAAAA or BBBBBBBB or could they read AAAABBBB or some other "mix" between the two?
I don't care about the ordering and what ends up being the final value. The important thing is just that no invalid value can ever be read from the location.

I realize that this may depend on the platform and C++ may not provide any promises for it. 
Would it be guaranteed for some platforms and would that involve using inline assembler to achieve it?

PS: I believe std::atomic would make such guarantees, but I think it would be far to much overhead to use for all load/store operations for object references.

Comment: What if you're writing a null-terminated string and haven't yet appended the terminating character? You probably do not want to be mixing reads and writes.

Comment: As a language designer it is **your** job to define what happens when a data race occurs. You may decide that an implementation has to deal with it in a way that only some results are possible (limiting performance), or you may decide that the underlying hardware decides what happens (not platform independent) or that anything is possible (difficult to program in). Asking us how your language that doesn't even exist yet will behave in a certain situation makes no sense.

Comment: I'm asking how C++ behaves, because I'm intending to compile to C++. I know that C/C++ has a lot of undefined behaviour, so my question is how to achieve a guarentee of "never read an invalid pointer" in C++.

Comment: Yes, you could use synchronization constructs that come with the language. Familiarize yourself with different locks, mutexes, atomic, etc.

Comment: Asking how C++ behaves will not help you, because the answer is that it behaves however you want it to behave. You need to show specific code when asking about the behavior. You should rephrase the question to either *How do I achieve [specific behavior] in C++* or *What is the behavior of [specific C++ code]*.

Comment: I have been testing std::atomic, but it seems to have a lot of overhead.

Comment: std::memory_order_relaxed provides no more guarantees than what you are asking. On x86/64 it will not produce more instructions, and it will not constrain reordering perfomed at compilation phase.

Comment: @nwp: I am trying to ask "how do I achieve this behaviour" but because std::atomic and std::mutex would hurt performance too much, I'm also trying to understand what guarentees I could get "for free". Both in portable C++ and on some common architectures.

Comment: @Oliv: Thanks! I'll look into that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

C++ makes no such guarantees, it depends on the hardware.
Typical hardware / processors, such as Arm, x86,amd64, as long as the writes are 32-bit aligned then 32-bit read and write operations will be atomic.

reading/writing 32bits a byte at a time (such as with strcpy, memcpy, etc), all bets are off - depends very much on the implementation of those functions (they tend to get lots of optimizations).

It gets more complicated on some platforms when there are multiple memory locations.

Say you have

```
extern int32 a;
extern int32 b;

a = 0x12345678;
b = 0x87654321;
```

Now, individually, a and b are written to atomically by thread 1, but an observer, thread 2, may "see" the value of B change before A.

This can happen due to hardware and software.
The software (the C++ compiler / optimizer), may rearrange your code if it thinks it would be better. (Or, the compiler may even avoid writing the values to a and b in some cases).

The hardware can also rearrange memory reads/writes at runtime - which is visible when thread1 and thread2 are running on different cores, and until core1 does something to synchronize its internal memory pipeline with the rest of the system, core2 may see something different. The Ia64 is pretty aggressive about these sorts of optimizations. X86 is not so much (as it would break too much legacy code I presume).

In C/C++, "volatile" basically lets you tell the compiler to be less aggressive with optimizations around this variable -- though exactly what it does depends on the implementation. Usually what it means is that the compiler won't optimize away reads/writes to volatile variables and generally won't rearrange accesses to them either.

This doesn't change what the processor might to at runtime though.
For that, you need to use the special "memory barrier" intrisics / operations. 
The details of these are complex, and are usually hidden behind such things as "atomic".

Oh, also, most systems have magical memory -- certain addresses which are reserved by the hardware for special purposes. Typically unless you are writing device drivers you won't run into this.

Comment: Hi joeking, thank you for elaborating on the subject.